# PrestaShop Paypal Module: Page Not Loading After Transaction

Tags: paypal, prestashop

I am using PrestaShop 1.5.2.0 and the PayPal 3.4.5 module.  After a customer completes a transaction using a credit card or PayPal account through the PayPal module, it will successfully process the transaction, charging the customer and putting in the order, but it then brings the customer to a page with an error.

**In Chrome:**

> No data received Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no
>   data. Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the
>   connection without sending any data.

**In Firefox:**

> The connection was reset The connection to the server was reset while
>   the page was loading.

I sent in a support ticket to PayPal and they responded saying:

> "This appears to be a script error on your cart's return page. The
>   return page that the buyer is redirected to is controlled by the
>   return URL that your cart passes in the transaction request to PayPal.
>   For buyers to get this error message on the return page after payment,
>   this needs to be investigated at the cart level. Please contact the
>   cart vendor to further investigate why the cart's return page is
>   returning that error."

Any help? Thanks.
- Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Is your return page expecting to receive data back, when the buyer is redirected to the page?  If so, what method are you using to return data back to your site?  If you are using the rm variable or using PDT, make sure that you have these configured correctly within your account.